# Video doesn't update after modifying the src property of its <source> element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to change the source of a `<video>`, but it is not playing the new video:

```
<body onload="setvid()">
    <div id="container">
            <video width="640" height="360" autoplay loop>
                <source id="srcc" src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setvid() {
            document.getElementById("srcc").src = "vid" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + ".mp4";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code is working for me, do you see any error in the console?

Comment: It should be executing, are you certain it isn't? It's more likely that it can't do what it needs to at the time it's executing.

Comment: The problem is not that the function doesn't run, but that you cannot change the `src` of the `source` element. You could have found out whether the function runs or not by adding a `console.log('runs')` to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) (emphasis mine):

> The `src` attribute gives the address of the media resource. The value must be a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces. This attribute must be present.
>
> Note: **Dynamically modifying a `source` element and its attribute when the element is already inserted in a `video` or `audio` element will have no effect. To change what is playing, just use the `src` attribute on the media element directly**, possibly making use of the `canPlayType()` method to pick from amongst available resources. Generally, manipulating source elements manually after the document has been parsed is an unnecessarily complicated approach.

So it seems you should assign the new source to the [`<video>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-video-element) element instead.

```
<div id="container">
        <video width="640" height="360" autoplay loop />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setvid() {
        document.querySelector('video').src = "...";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to work (thank you), but would document.getElementById(video id).src work as well? @FelixKling

Comment: or (maybe) even better, use library such as `video.js` to handle source modification actions, to provide better error handling & provide fallback video sources.

Comment: @Jax: Of course, you can use any way you want to get a reference to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Like Felix said, you shouldn't try to change the `src` attribute of a source element, according to [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element:the-source-element-12) spec note.

Instead, lets say you have:

```
<audio>
    <source src='./first-src'/>
</audio>
```

You can modify the media src like so:

```
<audio src='./second-src'/>
    <source src='./first-src'/>
</audio>
```